# trouble reading an array of class objects to screen from binary file

Tags: java, arrays, class, object, binaryfiles

Having trouble reading an array of class objects from a binary file onto the screen. So far, I've only been able to read the first object, even though I have 46 individual objects on the file. Here is the code:

```
private void readBinaryFile()
{
    ObjectInputStream ois = null;
    Person[] personData = null;
     try 
     {
         ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(FILE));
         personData = (Person[]) ois.readObject();

         for(Person p : personData)
         {  
             System.out.println(p.getName() +
                       "\t" + p.getRanking() +
                       "\t  " + p.getIDNumber());
         }
         ois.close();
     }
     catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
     catch (IOException e) {}
     catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {}
}
```

Even though the code compiles, when I call the method I get this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: Person cannot be cast to [LPerson;
```

Comment: `.readObject();` seems to return a single `Person` instead of an array of `Person`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your object stream contains a sequence of individual `Person` objects - not a `Person[]`.

If you want a `Person[]` in the stream, you should change your writing code - otherwise, you should presumably know how many people to read, and just use:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    Person person = (Person) ois.readObject();
    // Display the person
}
```

Comment: @mtk was that really necessary?